# How do I package this maven project or Java Application?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, dependencies

I'm creating a new project that run as a Java application(.jar), but I am confused about how to package the lib folder into the final jar file.
And I try to use Maven, but did not found some eligable plugins.

The project structure is here

[image: project structure]

---

**first**, I try to package with IDEA's build Artifact. it will extract all jar file into final jar and create a MANIFEST file, but the impact is there are some file like "*.SF, *.RSA", it destory the `java -jar xxx.jar`, But we can solve it by delete these .sf/.rsa file. Next problem occur, cause I use some springframework dependency, when extract these jar file, they will create a file like `spring.handles`, but its not complete.

**second**, I try to use MAVEN. I use the `maven-jar-plugin` `maven-compiler-plugin` `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy all jar file into final jar, and create the correct MANIFEST file. BUT a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` occur, I am DEAD!!!

---

So, the actual question is how can I package the lib folder into final executable jar???

Comment: You can use Maven shade plugin to create a fat jar.

Comment: I tried, but `maven-shade-plugin` package all the m2-repository's dependency into final jar, maybe my understanding is wrong. I need to add all jar file under lib folder into the final jar, and make it works, it seems `shade plugin` didn't work.

Comment: year, I found the solution. use IDEA build artifact option, and choose `copy to the output directory and link via manifest` and choose the correct `Main Class`, then IDEA will help us create a folder named `example_jar` under out folder, all your jar dependency file included here.